# Show animation on page while long process is running on server

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I want to implement an animation on my page when a long process, such as the Python Flask route below, is running that disappears after it finishes.  How can I do this?

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['GET','POST'])
def test():
    if request.method=="POST":
        if request.form.get('updatepaths')=='Update' and form.validate_on_submit():
            Fname = form.name.data
            Lname=form.name2.data
            TimeConsumingFunction(Fname)
            TimeConsumingFunction(Lname)
```

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to use JavaScript to make the request, display a spinner, then remove the spinner once the request completes.  For example, using jQuery, this example shows "waiting" (or whatever animation you put there) while the request is processing.

```
<a href="{{ url_for('test') }}" id="run">Run</a>
<span id="wait">Waiting</span>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var run_link = $('a#run');
    var run_wait = $('span#wait');
    run_wait.hide();

    $('a#run').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        run_link.hide()
        run_wait.show();

        $.post($(this).attr('href'), function(data) {
            run_wait.hide()
            run_link.show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

---

You can also use a task queue such as [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) to run tasks in the backround, rather than waiting for the request to finish.  This is beneficial because the task can continue running longer than the timeout for a request.